# MySQL: error is coming insde the insert statement of procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL. I'm trying to migrate data from one table to another. So I wrote a procedure. there is an insert statement in the procedure that throws an error. in phpmyadmin it only says the error is a connection error. bellow is the code

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE transfer_proc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE OLD_ID INT;
    DECLARE NEW_ID INT;
    DECLARE MYPLAN INT;
    DECLARE DAT DATE;
    DECLARE DUTY varchar(200) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE DS_DIV INT;
    DECLARE VEN varchar(200) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE REM varchar(200) DEFAULT "";

    DEClARE CURDAT 
        CURSOR FOR 
            select mp.ID,mp.MY_PLAN_ID,mp.DATE, mp.DUTY_PROGRAMME,mp.DS_DIVISION_ID,mp.VENUE,mp.REMARKS
            from my_plan_custom_programme mp;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
        
        OPEN CURDAT;

    CURLOOP: LOOP
        FETCH CURDAT INTO OLD_ID,MYPLAN,DAT,DUTY,DS_DIV,VEN,REM;
        IF finished = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE CURLOOP;
        END IF;
                
        INSERT INTO my_plan_all_saved_programmes(MY_PLAN_ID,DATE,DUTY_PROGRAMME,DS_DIVISION_ID,VENUE,REMARKS)
        VALUES(MYPLAN,DAT,DUTY,DS_DIV,VEN,REM);
        
        
        SELECT MAX(ID) INTO NEW_ID FROM my_plan_all_saved_programmes;

        INSERT INTO my_plan_all_saved_ds_division(MY_PLAN_CUS_ID,DS_DIV)
        SELECT NEW_ID,DS_DIV FROM my_plan_ds_division WHERE MY_PLAN_CUS_ID = OLD_ID;
        
        
        
    END LOOP CURLOOP;
    CLOSE CURDAT;
    
 END;
 //

DELIMITER ;
```

The error is comming in the last insert statement in the loop. without that insert statement the procedure gets created. but when it is there, it shows a connection error.

```
INSERT INTO my_plan_all_saved_ds_division(MY_PLAN_CUS_ID,DS_DIV)
SELECT NEW_ID,DS_DIV FROM my_plan_ds_division WHERE MY_PLAN_CUS_ID = OLD_ID;
```

Can someone please tell what is wrong in that query?

Comment: Pls share the **exact** error message with us! You should not be getting a connecton error in the middle of stored proc, this may be a phpmyadmin feature / bug, rather than an sql / mysql one!

Comment: There is no syntax issue with your code, please add the full error message and what you mean by connection error.

Comment: I think that CREATE TABLE for all used tables and some sample data (5-10 rows) as INSERT INTO will be useful for the problem reprodice.